# How to create magic geters and setters for doctrine ORM Entity in ZF2?

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

Hello I am new to ZendFrame work... I have followed some basic tutorials to build modules using doctrine orm.. I have successfully completed all the tutorials.

What I am trying now is to create Entities with magic getters and setters like this rather than coding all the getters and setters for each properties of entity class:

```
/* Magic getter to expose protected properties.
     *
     * @param string $property
     * @return mixed
     */

public function __get($property) {
    return $this->$property;
}

/**
 * Magic setter to save protected properties.
 *
 * @param string $property
 * @param mixed $value
 */
public function __set($property, $value) {
    $this->$property = $value;
}
```

This is how I used to handle the form in the controller:

```
        $user = new User();
        $builder = new DoctrineAnnotationBuilder($entityManager);
        $form = $builder->createForm($user);
        $form->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($entityManager,'Module/Entity/User'));
        $form->bind($user);

        if($this->getRequest()->isPost()) 
        {
              $form->setData($this->getRequest()->getPost());                 
              if($form->isValid()) {
                $u = $form->getData();
                var_dump($u);exit();
              }
        }
```

When i submit the form with correct data the form submits without any error but the properties of User object in the form are null:

```
object(Module\Entity\User)[272]
  private 'id' => null
  private 'firstname' => null
  private 'lastname' => null
  private 'email' => null
  private 'password' => null
  private 'rdate' => null
  private 'role' => null
```

This may be because Form object only relays on getters and setters of the object class binded to it.... but I am not sure... :(

Is there any solution for magic getters and setters to work with zend forms??

Answer (score 4):

First of all, this has nothing to do with Zend Framework 2. The DoctrineObject hydrator is responsible for hydrating the object.

Secondly, you instantiate the hydrator incorrectly. If you look at [its source](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/src/DoctrineModule/Stdlib/Hydrator/DoctrineObject.php), the second parameter is a boolean value indicating whether the public API of the entity should be used (getter/setter methods) or not.

Because you pass a string, it always evaluates to true which instructs the hydrator to actually use getter and setter methods, and because such methods does not exist, they are not getting called.

If you wish to bypass any class logic and just fetch/set values from the object with Reflection, you should instantiate the hydrator that way:

`$form->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($entityManager, false));`

However, this is a terrible idea in the OOP world - bypassing logic, using magic methods. Beginners tend to create such shortcuts. Follow some good tutorials on how to create [good, maintanable code](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/object-oriented-design-principles-and-the-5-ways-of-creating-solid-applications/) as I'm not going to cover such topics here.

Comment: Thnx @mike I was following the tutorial in which they passstring in the second argument I thought it may be name space to the class...

Comment: Official tutorial is outdated :)